# auto render ractive once when contains aysnc requests

Tags: javascript, mvvm, ractivejs

a ractive instance may include remote data and many components contains remote data. my target is render the whole ractive instance only one time when we get all the remote data.my sample code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/damngoto/5ub9fzte/2/), and i wanna know how to put all these into a plugin.

```
/*
DataGrid is a component that contains async request
*/
var DataGrid = Ractive.extend({
    template:'<ul>{{#datalist}}<li> {{.}}</li> {{/datalist}}</ul>',
    oninit: function(){
        var app = this
        // load init data by async request
        setTimeout(function() {
            app.set('datalist', [1, 3, 5])
            app.add('ajaxLoadedNum')
        }, 2000 * Math.random())
    }
})

Ractive.components.datagrid = DataGrid

var app = new Ractive({
    template: '#tmpl',
    data: {
        ajaxLoadedNum: 0,
        ajaxTotalNum: 3
    }
})

var listender = app.observe('ajaxLoadedNum', function(val, old){
    if (val == app.get('ajaxTotalNum')) {
        app.render('#c')
        listender.cancel()
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to handle the data retrieval in the components, then you need to gate the render by using a conditional in the template:

```
var DataGrid = Ractive.extend({
    template:'{{#if loaded}}<ul>{{#datalist}}<li> {{.}}</li> {{/datalist}}</ul>{{/if}}',
    ...
```

Then add a prop to the main component:

```
computed: {
    loaded: '${ajaxLoadedNum} === ${ajaxTotalNum}'
}
```

Here's full example:  http://jsfiddle.net/rkt8bgxm/

Comment: well, I think I do not describe the question clearly. Your answer definitely works, but it is not pretty and it is not a pugin. In our solution the component DataGrid imports a dependacy - ajaxLoadedNum, and what's more, the main component and any other components should also import this depencacy if they wanna render it in the same way. I have alreay wrote a method to  get this done, but it looks like 'ractiveless' - not a plugin, decorators, adaptors and so on.Just a method!

Comment: Do you just want to package those three components plus the method? Or are you looking to more broadly attach the async behavior to a set of component (or provide a base component that async components derive from)?

Comment: yeah, i wanna a base component that async components derive from